# Paypal Subscription, check if user paid for the next month

Tags: paypal, payment, webhooks, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-webhooks

i have a service, where i use Paypal subscription. Paypal has webhooks. The problem is that I don't understand which one i need to use, to know if user paid for the next month or not.

I used **Billing subscription renewed** but i was wrong. Actually there is no documentation, that explains Paypal webhooks

Hope you can help me with that

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and then I used

> PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED webhook event

It will be triggered when a subscription is made and when the subscription is renewed.

Comment: @IGentlich, Do you have any update about this thread? If it is useful, you could mark it as an answer

Comment: I have used payment sale completed, but it is missing the customer id, so there is no way to associate it to a customer.

Comment: I think this is meant to be the right answer, but I didn't say anything within the resource of the webhook event that would allow me to associate it with the PayPal subscription, such as a PayPal subscription ID. 

I'm going to continue logging them as they are fired and see if I can make sense of how to associated a completed sale with the subscription. I can't use a subscriber since they can have a few different subscriptions at the same time in our system.

Comment: If anyone finds this thread and wonders about the customer id, you can set a custom_id parameter on your subscription button which you can use to specify some sort of identifier from your own system, like a transaction id or user id.  When the PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED webhook event is fired, the payload will contain a custom field containing that same value.  You can then use this to identify your user in your db.